# Ruby on Rails, DELETE request doesn't work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Just getting into programming, first project I've tried. I'm trying to follow a YouTube video to make a friends app.

(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fmyvWz5TUWg)

I'm having problems with deleting, and this is in two instances.

So whenever I press my "Delete this friend" button, rather than deleting, it acts as a show button.

The delete button is at the end of a row on my friends table, when I inspect the button, the code is as follows:

```
<a data-confirm="Are you sure?" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/friends/7">Delete</a>
```

(In the editor, it is:)

```
 <td><%= link_to 'Delete', friend, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, class: "btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm" %></td> which is in a <tr> </tr> tag, inside a <tbody> </tbody>
```

However it seems to just bring me to the page, http://localhost:3000/friends/7, rather than deleting.

I do have another button on the show page, for a destroy this friend, this one works:
`<button type="submit">Destroy this friend</button>`

Ive checked my friends controller, and it has a working destroy:

```
 # DELETE /friends/1 or /friends/1.json
  def destroy
    @friend.destroy!

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to friends_url, notice: "Friend was successfully destroyed." }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
```

The second time I noticed this issue was further on in the video, where he creates a user sign in, using the devise gem. My user signin worked correctly, I had linked all of the new features (sign up, sign in, sign out, and edit profile to my NAV bar), but when I went to signout, once again it couldn't read the DELETE properly, and read it as a GET, leading to the error message:

```
No route matches [GET] "/users/sign_out"
Rails.root: C:/railsfriends/friends
```

My Sign out button code is as follows:

```
<li class="nav-item">
            <%= link_to "Sign out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete, class:"nav-link"%>
        </li>
```

The error message in my chrome console also confirmed that the reason for the error was a GET request was being attempted, rather than a DELETE:

For reference, my route is

```
destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)                                                                       devise/sessions#destroy.
```

ChatGPT suggested a few things, relating to TurboLinks, Javascript Libraries, I tried using its suggestions, but I hadn't properly committed my code to GitHub, and confused myself beyond being able to remove the changes manually.

I started again (this time using GitHub), here is the link:

https://github.com/daneaston1/friends/tree/Sign-out---broken-

Any help would be appreciated, I've spent ages trying to figure this out, and restarting my project etc.

Apologies that this likely looks like a mess, this is my first stack overflow post.

Rails Version: 7.1.3.2
Ruby: 3.2.3
node: v20.11.1
yarn: 1.22.21
bootstrap: 4.5

Comment: Add the rails version to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How this worked was changed recently, change `link_to` to `button_to`.

Comment: Oh wow, it  was that simple. Thanks very much! Ive spent the last 3 hours trying to fix it.

Comment: My recommendation is to try out the Rails generators, especially the `scaffold` generator just type `rails g scaffold` in your project for the help. Then you can look at the working code Rails itself produces for a simple CRUD interface.